# How to view / retrieve a FormData object from request body (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, form-data

Hello and thanks in advance,

I'm writing a video uploader web app that uploads a video and saves it to a mongo database. I've searched online for a couple days to find out how to get that DataForm object out of the request body so I can save it in the database.

I'm just not sure what I'm looking for on the server side. How do you get the video data out of the request body? Here's my code:

```
//client side
upload: function(event) {
        // prevent default browser submit
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        var fileInput = this._("file1").files[0];

        if (!fileInput) {
            return;
        }

        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file1", fileInput);
        api.addContent(formdata, this.updateCB);
}

//api call
addContent: function(data, cb) {
        var url = "/api/content";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {'Authorization': localStorage.token},
            success: function(res) {
                if (cb)
                    cb(true, res);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                // if there is an error, remove the login token
                delete localStorage.token;
                if (cb)
                    cb(false, status);
            }
        });
}

//server side
app.post('/api/content', function (req,res) {
    user = User.verifyToken(req.headers.authorization, function(user) {
        if (user) {
        // req.body.data should work
        Content.create({data:req.body.data,user:user.id}, function(err,content) {
        if (err) {
            res.sendStatus(403);
            return;
        }
        res.json({content:'content saved'});
        });
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(403);
        }
    });
});
```

And here's a screenshot of the request body in chrome:
[Request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmfMr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to parse through the formdata object.

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty');


    app.post('/api/content', function (req,res) {
        console.log(req);
        // validate the supplied token
        user = User.verifyToken(req.headers.authorization, function(user) {
            if (user) {

            var form = new multiparty.Form();
            form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            var video_path = String(files.file1[0].path);
            Content.create({video:video_path,user:user.id}, function(err,content) {
            if (err) {
                res.sendStatus(403);
                return;
            }
            res.json({content:content});
            });
            });
            } else {
                res.sendStatus(403);
            }
        });
    });
```